# Redirect to "/" route in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-4.4

I'm trying to redirect to the "/" route (same page) after a form submission:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
```

My approach:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('/');
```

Gives me the following error:

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/" as such route does not exist.

Comment: Why not name route more verbose - home, index, main?

Comment: doesnt that change the url? Edit: I get what you mean now, Im new to symfony, thanks. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you have to name the route, like:

```
/**
* @Route("/", name="homepage")
*/
```

and then:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */


return $this->redirect('/');
```

Comment: Since I'm using xampp this redirects to xampp's dashboard but I'm sure it would work on symfony's server, thanks.